# Multi-IP ping from a DNS

Tags: dns, subdomain, ping

Get ping from this subdomain:
**dd.drproxy.pro**
Each ping is displayed as an IP.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the nslookup Result in youe command!

This screenshot is in Chinese Language, but it may help you understand this:
[image: NSLookUp Result of 'dd.drproxy.pro']

It shows this domain has binded with multiple A-Record, and a CNAME to `do.drproxy.pro` and it has more A-Records binding to it!

[image: Much More A-Record of do.drproxy.pro]

Try create the same situation with you own domains, I think you'll got

Comment: I did an A-RECORD.
But at any moment, ping was not set to an IP!
Do you really need C-name too? Or does a special configuration do that?

Comment: I'm not an expert in configuring DNS Server, but it seems to use a techonolgy similar with load-balance. called 'dynamic DNS load-balance'.

Comment: Thanks  刘浩宇
Thank you for your information, I will certainly search for this